# How to handle iframes on a webpage

Tags: html, go, iframe, web-scraping, chromedp

I want to get the HTML source of the iframe present on the [webpage](https://www.tokopedia.com/chocoapple/ready-stock-bnib-iphone-128gb-7-plus-jet-black-garansi-apple-1-tahun-10?src=topads). I am using chromedp package with Go. How to handle the iframes with chromedp package? The documentation is very less so couldn't find a way.

Links:

[chromedp](https://github.com/knq/chromedp)

[Google-doc](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Gyu5f5QL_N5OkchOqMC8KJK_tvpd4UNMVZvsgkQhHzA/edit?usp=sharing) to get more details of my task.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Does it select with XPath like `//iframe`? Could you show you code to better understand the problem?

Comment: @EugeneLisitsky: Please check the [file](https://gist.github.com/yogesh-desai/cfb484cd0349fe18cb8e048f38616a6c) for my code so far. I am able to get "webyclip-widget-3" iframe with its "ID". But unable to get the complete HTML under it. "Inspect" element shows the videos and "img" tags. I want that "img" tags to extract the videos links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After many attempts, Finally, I found the way and solved my query. You can check my [GitHub](https://github.com/yogesh-desai/WebCrawlerTokopedia) repository for this query. Thank you.
To get the iframe contents we can use Javascript. Way to do it with chromedp is as below,

```
cdp.EvaluateAsDevTools("document.getElementById('IFRAME-ID').contentWindow.document.body.outerHTML;", RESULT-BUFFER),
```

Comment: how to handle javascript alert and get the text inside it. I notice there is `Page.javascriptDialogOpening` in the method

Comment: I get this error: Error: Blocked a frame with origin "https://www.someSite.com" from accessing a cross-origin frame.